# Files permission - problem with an exception to grant to specific user

Tags: centos, permissions, users, group, acl

As part of an exercice at my University, we need to do the following task:

- Respect the «least Privileges» rule.
- Create 5 users groups, each one has its own folder (G1 => Folder_G1)
- Grant user G1_Stefan the right to read the folder Folder_G2

So what I did is the following:

```
[Stefan@centos---exam ffhs]$ getfacl verkauf
# file: verkauf
# owner: root
# group: Verkauf
user::rwx
user:Stefan:r--
group::rwx
group:Technik:---
group:HR:---
group:Projekt:---
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

Stefan has access to the folder "hr" because he is an employee of the HR department. He is nevertheless a special user because he should have read access only to the "verkauf" (= sales). All his colleagues of the HR department have no right to access the "verkauf" folder.

This is why, for the "verkauf" folder, I set special ACL permissions to the group HR (---) and an exception for the user Stefan (r--).

The thing is that it does not work:

```
[Stefan@centos---exam ffhs]$ cd verkauf
bash: cd: verkauf: Permission denied
```

And I do not know how to get around with it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to have search (execute) `+x` permission for the directory to able `cd` into it.